# Spring-Boot logging with log4j2?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, spring-boot, log4j2

I'm using `spring-boot-starter`, and would like to configure `log4j2.xml` to log asynchron + different content to different logfiles.

I created the log4j2 file, but `Spring` still uses the spring-boot default logging. How can I switch the logging?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I've a better way:

1. Exclude logback logger:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add log4j2 boot starter:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```

Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-log4j-for-logging

Enjoy!

Comment: I think you meant : "1. exclude logback framework" instead of "exclude slf4j logger" right?

Comment: Also make sure you use <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId> if you use log4j2, since <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId> is valid but won't work for log4j2

Comment: For me I has to add these two            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
              <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
              <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
              <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          </exclusion>         
      </exclusions>

Comment: For me using Gradle I just did this:

`configurations.all*.exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'`

and then in my dependencies {} section I added `runtime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'`

Comment: For me it does not work: all logs are printing to console.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

1. Exclude spring-boot-starter-logging e.g.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add dependencies for your logging interface e.g. slf4j

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Add other logging implementations pointing to chosen logging interface e.g.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
4. Add your target logging implementation e.g.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.2</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.2</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

And it should work.

Comment: Nowadays there is also `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` since spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE. Just for reference.

Comment: This does not work for me as well: all logs are printing to console.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me. Having two additional exclusions. Else Application was not picking up log4j and was had conflict

*Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>            
    </exclusions>           
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```