# Spring Boot logging with Log4j2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j2

Written simple POC to prove and test Spring Boot and log4j2 compatibility. Once successful I will move it to real application.

Please refer my POC source code:
https://github.com/Dennyss/SpringBootLog4j2POC

I  know/read about Spring version and log4j2 compatibility from:
[How to set up Spring Boot and log4j2 properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389512/how-to-set-up-spring-boot-and-log4j2-properly)

Found and tried recommendations described here:
[Spring-Boot logging with log4j2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683210/spring-boot-logging-with-log4j2)

But still not working. The problem is that both application logs and Spring logs are printing to console only.

Please refer maven dependencies below (from POC):

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If I don't exclude Spring's logback and don't add boot-starter-log4j2 then application logs are printing to application file but Spring logs are not printing at all. I feel the problem somewhere with dependencies. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Spring Boot [Logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) documentation, the location of the logging configuration file can be specified using the `logging.config` property.  I noticed that your start.sh script is passing `-Dlog4j.configurationFile`.  Normally, this would be sufficient for direct Log4J 2 integration, but Spring Boot uses `logging.config`.

After switching to this, it writes to the log files:

```
java -Dlogging.config=/share/LogPOC/log4j2.xml -cp poc.jar:libs/* com.poc.logger.Application
```

Comment: Tried this today, got Error message to console: "ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console." but all work great. I see app logs in application.log, Spring in spring-framework.log and all other in other.log. Thanks for your help!

Comment: As per log4j documentation it expects '-Dlog4j.configurationFile', not sure if it's initialized correctly (error message explains the same).