# Spring boot log configuration with camunda bpmn

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j2

i know there are a few similar topics outthere, but none of these solved my problem regarding logging in spring boot applications.

The problem is this error message: Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'classpath:log4j2.xml'
I try to redirect the standard output from console to a separate log4j2.xml file but i does not work as you can see the error.

My pom.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

     <groupId>com.example.workflow</groupId>
     <artifactId>P1</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

     <properties>
         <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
         <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
         <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
     </properties>

     <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
           <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
              <version>2.7.3</version>
              <type>pom</type>
              <scope>import</scope>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
             <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
             <artifactId>camunda-bom</artifactId>
             <version>7.18.0</version>
             <scope>import</scope>
             <type>pom</type>
             </dependency>
           </dependencies>
         </dependencyManagement>

         <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest</artifactId>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp</artifactId>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-engine-plugin-spin</artifactId>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.spin</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-spin-dataformat-all</artifactId>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
          </dependency>

         <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
           <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
           <version>1.18.22</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>

  
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
          </dependency>
  
          <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.16.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
           </dependency>

      </dependencies>

      <build>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.7.3</version>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
       </build>
</project>
```

My log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
 <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="File" fileName="logs/camunda.log"
                 filePattern="logs/camunda-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers></Configuration>
```

This file is located under src/main/resources which also includes the application.properties file holding only this line "logging.config=log4j2.xml" or what i also tried was to put the classpath before so "logging.config=classpath:log4j2.xml"
The location of lof4j2.xml is also in resource folder but i also copied it to root level and so on nothing works.

Additionally i can see that in the folder target/classes there are all files located so the file is definitly here.

In maven dependencies i found this:
[overview maven dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjGUi.png)

Please can anyone help me out with this.

Here is the complete error message:

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'log4j2.xml'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@3:16 - no applicable action for 
[Appenders], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@4:53 - no applicable action for             
[Console], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][Console]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:91 - no applicable action for     
[PatternLayout], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][Console] 
[PatternLayout]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@8:74 - no applicable action for     
[RollingFile], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@9:91 - no applicable action for 
[PatternLayout], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile] 
[PatternLayout]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@10:23 - no applicable action for 
[Policies], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][Policies]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@11:57 - no applicable action for 
[SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders] 
[RollingFile][Policies][SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@13:48 - no applicable action for 
[DefaultRolloverStrategy], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders] 
[RollingFile][DefaultRolloverStrategy]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@16:14 - no applicable action for 
[Loggers], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@17:28 - no applicable action for 
[Root], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Root]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@18:41 - no applicable action for 
[AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Root][AppenderRef]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@19:38 - no applicable action for 
[AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Root][AppenderRef]]
```

at
`org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:179) at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:66) at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:57) at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:132) at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:332) at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298) at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246) at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223) at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66) at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:344) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) at com.example.workflow.Application.main(Application.java:10) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@3:16 - no applicable action for [Appenders], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@4:53 - no applicable action for [Console], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][Console]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:91 - no applicable action for [PatternLayout], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][Console][PatternLayout]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@8:74 - no applicable action for [RollingFile], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@9:91 - no applicable action for [PatternLayout], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][PatternLayout]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@10:23 - no applicable action for [Policies], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][Policies]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@11:57 - no applicable action for [SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][Policies][SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@13:48 - no applicable action for [DefaultRolloverStrategy], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][DefaultRolloverStrategy]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@16:14 - no applicable action for [Loggers], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@17:28 - no applicable action for [Root], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Root]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@18:41 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Root][AppenderRef]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@19:38 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Root][AppenderRef]] at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:344) at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298) at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246) at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223) at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66) at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:344) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) at com.example.workflow.Application.main(Application.java:10) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@3:16 - no applicable action for [Appenders], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@4:53 - no applicable action for [Console], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][Console]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@5:91 - no applicable action for [PatternLayout], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][Console][PatternLayout]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@8:74 - no applicable action for [RollingFile], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@9:91 - no applicable action for [PatternLayout], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][PatternLayout]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@10:23 - no applicable action for [Policies], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][Policies]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@11:57 - no applicable action for [SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][Policies][SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@13:48 - no applicable action for [DefaultRolloverStrategy], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][DefaultRolloverStrategy]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@16:14 - no applicable action for [Loggers], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@17:28 - no applicable action for [Root], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Root]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@18:41 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Root][AppenderRef]] ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@19:38 - no applicable action for [AppenderRef], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Loggers][Root][AppenderRef]] at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:179) at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:66) at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:57) at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:132) at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(Logging     ApplicationListener.java:332) ... 18 more [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring-Boot logging with log4j2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683210/spring-boot-logging-with-log4j2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a proper solution using spring boot profiles this works like a charm.

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="src/main/resources/spring.log}"/>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<encoder>
  <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
</encoder>
<file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
  <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d</fileNamePattern>
</rollingPolicy>
</appender>
<springProfile name="!dev">
    <root level="INFO">
        <!-- This is for the local environment -->
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</springProfile>

<springProfile name="dev">
    <include resource="com/google/cloud/spring/logging/logback-json-appender.xml"/>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_JSON"/>
    </root>
</springProfile>
```

With this in application.properties: spring.profiles.active=dev2

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

If the object is simply to log the log output of certain packages to a a separate file, as stated in the comment, then yoyu can achieve this with the existing logback loggging config.

Declare an additional appender (e.g.g file), then reference this appender in the logger configuration.

Working example:

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>camunda.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>


  <!-- camunda -->
  <logger name="org.camunda" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </logger>

  <!-- common dependencies -->
  <logger name="org.apache.ibatis" level="info"/>
  <logger name="javax.activation" level="info"/>
  <logger name="org.springframework" level="info"/>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </root>

</configuration>
```

This will write the INFO log level of all classes below org.camunda to camunda.log

Comment: Thanks for responsing, but this does not work as expected. I have to use log4j2 because i want to redirect the output from camunda bpmn to a separate file. This only works with log4j2 as i read.

Comment: This does not require log4j2. Please see my updated answer